# Existence of a rational isomorphism between circles

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, circles, rational-functions

Reference: "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" (Silverman, second edition),
Exercise 1.11. (b).

Consider two circles $X^2 + Y^2 = p \cdot Z^2$ and $X^2 + Y^2 = q \cdot Z^2$.

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then the
circles are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. I understand why (essentially
because $p$ and $q$ are the sum of two squares, such that both circles are
isomorphic to the projective line over $\mathbb{Q}$).

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, then the
circles are not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. According to Silverman's
exercise, it is true, but I do not understand why (but I understand that
there is no rational point on such circles).

If $p = 1\ (mod\ 4)$ and $q = 3\ (mod\ 4)$, I do not know whether the circles
are isomorphic or not over $\mathbb{Q}$ (perhaps depending upon a further
condition).

Comment: If you understand that the first has a rational point and the second doesn't, then that would seem to settle the question of whether those circles are isomorphic over $\Bbb Q$, no?

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then the circles are both isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the projective line, and thus, by combining both isomorphisms (which are invertible), the circles are isomorphic to each other. Also, if $p$ or $q$ is not congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, such an intermediate isomorphism to the projective line does not exists any longer (at least one of the circles is not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the projective line). But there may be a direct rational isomorphism between the circles, mapping irrational points to irrational points.

Comment: I was referring to your final paragraph treating the $p=1$ and $q=3$ case: the circle with $p$ has a rational point, while the circle with $q$ does not. Isomorphisms over $\Bbb Q$ preserve $\Bbb Q$-rational points, so the $p$-circle cannot be isomorphic to the $q$-circle. (In fact, there cannot even be a map from the $p$-circle to the $q$-circle: the image of a $\Bbb Q$-point under a $\Bbb Q$-morphism is again a $\Bbb Q$-point.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand your argument for the case $p = 1\ (mod\ 4)$ and $q = 1\ (mod\ 4)$, I should have figured out myself. The really interesting case is thus $p = 3\ (mod\ 4)$ and $q = 3\ (mod\ 4)$.

Comment: If $p = 3\ (mod\ 4)$ then $X^2 + Y^2 = pZ^2$ has no $\mathbb{Q}_p$ points and has $\mathbb{Q}_q$ points for any $q \ne p$.  (Serre, "A Course in Arithmetic", chapter 2.)

Comment: Correction to previous comment:  has $\mathbb{Q}_q$ points for any $q \ne p, q \gt 2.$